# Quickly switching Scala versions from CLI

Tags: scala, multiple-versions, scala-repl

[`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager) enables quick selection of alternative Node version to work with. Does Scala have a similar way of quickly switching different versions in the current shell? For example, say I want to start REPL with 2.12.10, then executing something something like

```
scala use 2.12.10
```

would greet with

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_202).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
```

Note the question is not about SBT via `scalaVersion`, but using `scala` command directly from the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively to scala-runners, there's also [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/usage#use), which is a more general tool but also supports scala. For example, command:

```
sdk use scala 2.12.10
```

sets scala to 2.12.10 for current shell session.

Answer (score 3):

[dwijnand/scala-runners](https://github.com/dwijnand/scala-runners)

> An alternative implementation of the Scala distribution's runners:
>   `scala`, `scalac`, `scaladoc`, and `scalap` (no fsc). They are implemented as
>   thin shell scripts around Coursier's coursier launch to add some Scala
>   runners-specific (power) options.

provide a quick way of starting different versions

```
scala --scala-version 2.12.10
```

and even [development versions](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/coming-soon-scala-2-12-11-scala-2-13-2/4003/10?u=mario-galic) from

```
https://scala-ci.typesafe.com/artifactory/scala-integration
https://scala-ci.typesafe.com/artifactory/scala-pr-validation-snapshots
```

for example

```
scala --scala-version 2.13.2-bin-81d1da3
```

or particular [pull request](https://github.com/dwijnand/scala-runners/pull/5)

```
scala --scala-pr 8960
```

Comment: Also what I do is having two versions of **Ammonite** with two bash alias `amm-12` & `amm-13`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez How do you go about quickly changing just the minor version, say when checking if bug is present only in particular minor version?

Comment: I haven't got that far! Agree that **scala-runners** is the best alternative we had.